# Custom UITableView not appearing on iPhone or iPad

Tags: ios, objective-c

It's an old app, and uses hard coded values, however, there is no display of the table at all - whilst I realise it would mean I need to hardcode each value for each device, at the moment I can't even see the tableview to start doing that.

```
-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    
    if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
        myCustomTableView=[[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(300, 180, 236, 672) style:UITableViewStylePlain];
    else {
        myCustomTableView=[[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(113, 100, 196, 372) style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
    }
    [myCustomTableView setDelegate:self];
    [myCustomTableView setDataSource:self];
    [myCustomTableView setSeparatorStyle:UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleSingleLine];
    [myCustomTableView setSeparatorColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    myCustomTableView.opaque = NO;
    myCustomTableView.clipsToBounds = YES;
    myCustomTableView.layer.cornerRadius=8.0;
    [myCustomTableView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
[self.view addSubview:myCustomTableView];
```

It's worked in older versions of iOS (perhaps iOS 10.0 downwards

Added extra coding here;

```
-(UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    static NSString *cellIndentifer=@"Cell";
    
    UITableViewCell *cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIndentifer];
    if (cell == nil) {
        //cell=[[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIndentifer] autorelease];
        NSLog(@" gell is allocating");
        cell =
        [[[UITableViewCell alloc]
          initWithFrame:CGRectZero
          reuseIdentifier:cellIndentifer]
         autorelease];
        
        UIImageView *cellImageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(4, 4, 35, 47)];
        cellImageView.tag = leftImageViewTag;
        [cellImageView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleToFill];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:cellImageView];
        [cellImageView release];
        
        
        UIImageView *cellImageViewSubView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(13, 12,18 , 24)];
        cellImageViewSubView.tag = leftImageSubViewTag;
        [cellImageViewSubView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleToFill];
        //[cellImageViewSubView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"sp4.png"]];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:cellImageViewSubView];
        [cellImageViewSubView release];
        
        
        UIButton *myAddButton=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        [myAddButton setFrame:CGRectMake(5, 10, 40, 40)];
        [myAddButton setTag:leftAddButtonTag];
        [myAddButton setHidden:YES];
        if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] respondsToSelector:@selector(isMultitaskingSupported)]) {
            [myAddButton setImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"add@2x" ofType:@"png"]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        }
        else {
            [myAddButton setImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"add" ofType:@"png"]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        }

        [myAddButton addTarget:self action:@selector(addCellForCamera) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [myAddButton setTitle:@"" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:myAddButton];
        
        UIButton *myMinusButton=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        [myMinusButton setFrame:CGRectMake(140, 10, 40, 40)];
        [myMinusButton setTag:rightMinusButtonTag];
        if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] respondsToSelector:@selector(isMultitaskingSupported)]) {
            [myMinusButton setImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"minus@2x" ofType:@"png"]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            
        }
        else {
            [myMinusButton setImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"minus" ofType:@"png"]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            
        }
        [myMinusButton setHidden:YES];
        [myMinusButton addTarget:self action:@selector(minusCellForCamera:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:myMinusButton];
        
        CameraButton *myCameraButton=[CameraButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        [myCameraButton setFrame:CGRectMake(135, 10, 50, 30)];
        [myCameraButton setTag:myCameraButtonTag];
        [myCameraButton setImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"theme_Camera" ofType:@"png"]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [myCameraButton setHidden:YES];
        [myCameraButton addTarget:self action:@selector(CellForCameraButtonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [myCameraButton setIndexpath:indexPath];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:myCameraButton];               
        
        
        UIImageView *cellImageView2 = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(150, 4, 25, 25)];
        cellImageView2.tag = tickImageViewTag;
        [cellImageView2 setHidden:YES];
        [cellImageView2 setImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"click" ofType:@"png"]]];
        [cellImageView2 setContentMode:UIViewContentModeCenter];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:cellImageView2];
        [cellImageView2 release];
        
        
        UILabel *mylabel=[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(60, 5, 130, 30)];
        mylabel.tag=middleLabelTag;
        [mylabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        mylabel.textColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
        
        [cell addSubview:mylabel];
        [mylabel release];
        cell.backgroundView =
        [[[UIImageView alloc] init] autorelease];
        
        
        
        UIImageView *backgroundSelection=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"grey-hover" ofType:@"png"]]];
        cell.selectedBackgroundView=[backgroundSelection autorelease];
        
        
        
    }
    
    [(CameraButton *)[cell viewWithTag:myCameraButtonTag] setIndexpath:indexPath];
    UIImage *rowBackground;
    
    NSInteger sectionRows = [tableView numberOfRowsInSection:[indexPath section]];
    NSInteger row = [indexPath row];
    
    if (row == 0)
    {
        rowBackground = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"top-row" ofType:@"png"]];
        
    }
    else if (row == sectionRows - 1)
    {
        
        rowBackground = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"btm-row" ofType:@"png"]];
        
        
    }
    else
    {
        rowBackground = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"row" ofType:@"png"]];
        
        
    }
    ((UIImageView *)cell.backgroundView).image = rowBackground;
    
    if (self.tickCurrentPath == indexPath) {
        [[cell viewWithTag:tickImageViewTag] setHidden:NO];
    }
    else {
        [[cell viewWithTag:tickImageViewTag] setHidden:YES];
    }
    
    cell.selectionStyle=UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

    
    if (indexPath.section == 0) {
        if (indexPath.row == [customArray count] ) {
            cell.selectionStyle=UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
            [[cell viewWithTag:myCameraButtonTag] setHidden:YES];
            [[cell viewWithTag:leftAddButtonTag] setHidden:NO];
            [[cell viewWithTag:rightMinusButtonTag] setHidden:NO];
            [[cell viewWithTag:leftImageViewTag] setHidden:YES];
            [[cell viewWithTag:tickImageViewTag] setHidden:YES];
            
            [[cell viewWithTag:leftImageSubViewTag] setHidden:YES];
            
            if ([customArray count]==0) {
                UIButton *button=(UIButton *)[cell viewWithTag:rightMinusButtonTag];
                [button setEnabled:NO];         }
            else {
                UIButton *button=(UIButton *)[cell viewWithTag:rightMinusButtonTag];
                [button setEnabled:YES];
            }
            
            UILabel *middleText=(UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:middleLabelTag];
            middleText.text=@"";
        }
        else {
            [[cell viewWithTag:myCameraButtonTag] setHidden:NO];
            
            [[cell viewWithTag:leftImageViewTag] setHidden:NO];
            [[cell viewWithTag:leftAddButtonTag] setHidden:YES];
            [[cell viewWithTag:rightMinusButtonTag] setHidden:YES];
            
            //batter-sm-blnk.png
            UIImageView *batteryImageView=(UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:leftImageViewTag];
            [batteryImageView setImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"batter-sm-blnk" ofType:@"png"]]];
            
            UILabel *middleText=(UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:middleLabelTag];
            NSDictionary *tempDict=[customArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            //  NSLog(@"tempdict contains %@",customArray);
            middleText.text=[tempDict objectForKey:@"Cell_Text"];
            
            NSData *imageData=[tempDict objectForKey:@"Image"];
            
            NSLog(@"size of image:  %d",[imageData length]);
            if ([imageData length]>1) {
                [[cell viewWithTag:leftImageSubViewTag] setHidden:NO];
                //NSData *imageData=[tempDict objectForKey:@"Image"];
                UIImageView *batteryImageView=(UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:leftImageSubViewTag];
                [batteryImageView setImage:[UIImage imageWithData:imageData]];
            }else {
                [[cell viewWithTag:leftImageSubViewTag] setHidden:YES];
            }
            
            
            
            
            
        }
        return cell;
    }
    else if (indexPath.section == 1) {
        UILabel *middleText=(UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:middleLabelTag];
        middleText.text=[colorArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [[cell viewWithTag:myCameraButtonTag] setHidden:YES];
        [[cell viewWithTag:leftImageSubViewTag] setHidden:YES];
        
        [[cell viewWithTag:leftAddButtonTag] setHidden:YES];
        [[cell viewWithTag:rightMinusButtonTag] setHidden:YES];
        [[cell viewWithTag:leftImageViewTag] setHidden:NO];
        UIImageView *batteryImageView=(UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:leftImageViewTag];
        [batteryImageView setImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[cellImages_Battery objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] ofType:@"png"]]];
        
        return cell;
        
    }
    
    else if (indexPath.section == 2)  {
        [[cell viewWithTag:leftImageSubViewTag] setHidden:YES];
        
        [[cell viewWithTag:leftImageViewTag] setHidden:NO];
        [[cell viewWithTag:myCameraButtonTag] setHidden:YES];
        
        
        UIImageView *batteryImageView=(UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:leftImageViewTag];
        [batteryImageView setImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[flagImageArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] ofType:@"png"]]];
        
        
        [[cell viewWithTag:rightMinusButtonTag] setHidden:YES];
        [[cell viewWithTag:leftAddButtonTag] setHidden:YES];
        UILabel *middleText=(UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:middleLabelTag];
        middleText.text=[flagArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        return cell;
    }
    else if (indexPath.section == 3)  {
        [[cell viewWithTag:leftImageSubViewTag] setHidden:YES];
        
        [[cell viewWithTag:leftImageViewTag] setHidden:NO];
        [[cell viewWithTag:myCameraButtonTag] setHidden:YES];
        
        
        UIImageView *batteryImageView=(UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:leftImageViewTag];
        [batteryImageView setImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[flagImageArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row+5] ofType:@"png"]]];
        
        
        [[cell viewWithTag:rightMinusButtonTag] setHidden:YES];
        [[cell viewWithTag:leftAddButtonTag] setHidden:YES];
        UILabel *middleText=(UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:middleLabelTag];
        middleText.text=[flagArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row+5];
        return cell;
    }
    else if (indexPath.section == 4)  {
        [[cell viewWithTag:leftImageSubViewTag] setHidden:YES];
        
        [[cell viewWithTag:leftImageViewTag] setHidden:NO];
        [[cell viewWithTag:myCameraButtonTag] setHidden:YES];
        
        
        UIImageView *batteryImageView=(UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:leftImageViewTag];
        [batteryImageView setImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[flagImageArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row+10] ofType:@"png"]]];
        
        
        [[cell viewWithTag:rightMinusButtonTag] setHidden:YES];
        [[cell viewWithTag:leftAddButtonTag] setHidden:YES];
        UILabel *middleText=(UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:middleLabelTag];
        middleText.text=[flagArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row+10];
        return cell;
    }
    else if (indexPath.section == 5)  {
        [[cell viewWithTag:leftImageSubViewTag] setHidden:YES];
        
        [[cell viewWithTag:leftImageViewTag] setHidden:NO];
        [[cell viewWithTag:myCameraButtonTag] setHidden:YES];
        
        
        UIImageView *batteryImageView=(UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:leftImageViewTag];
        [batteryImageView setImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[flagImageArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row+15] ofType:@"png"]]];
        
        
        [[cell viewWithTag:rightMinusButtonTag] setHidden:YES];
        [[cell viewWithTag:leftAddButtonTag] setHidden:YES];
        UILabel *middleText=(UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:middleLabelTag];
        middleText.text=[flagArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row+15];
        return cell;
    }
    else if (indexPath.section == 6)  {
        [[cell viewWithTag:leftImageSubViewTag] setHidden:YES];
        
        [[cell viewWithTag:leftImageViewTag] setHidden:NO];
        [[cell viewWithTag:myCameraButtonTag] setHidden:YES];
        
        
        UIImageView *batteryImageView=(UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:leftImageViewTag];
        [batteryImageView setImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[flagImageArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row+20] ofType:@"png"]]];
        
        
        [[cell viewWithTag:rightMinusButtonTag] setHidden:YES];
        [[cell viewWithTag:leftAddButtonTag] setHidden:YES];
        UILabel *middleText=(UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:middleLabelTag];
        middleText.text=[flagArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row+20];
        return cell;
    }
    
    return cell;
    
    
}
```

Comment: Do a little debugging... are `numberOfRowsInSection` and `cellForRowAtIndexPath` being called? If you use Debug View Hierarchy, does your table view exist? Does it have cells? Is it there, but somehow hidden or positioned off-screen?

Comment: You are onto something, it doesn't seem to be getting called

Comment: `viewWillAppear` is an odd place to be setting up your table view. If that's all of your code, you never add the table view to the view hierarchy. Where is your `[self.view addSubview: myCustomTableView];` ?

Comment: Sorry I had forgot to add that, it actually is straight after the last line above ( I have edited the code), so it was there, just not working :/

Comment: OK - I feel silly, but I have moved to viewDidLoad and it works....! Thank you so much DonMag

Answer (score 0):

As DonMag mentioned in the comments, at a minimum you need to include the two UITableViewDataSource methods `numberOfRowsInSection` and `cellForRowAtIndexPath` for any cells to be rendered for the tableview.

Are you adding myCustomTableView to the view hierarchy somehow somewhere else in your code (i.e. self.view addSubview:)?

Here's a very simple example using your code as a base for generating a test tableview programmatically:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController () <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>
@property (strong, nullable) UITableView *myCustomTableView;
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
        self.myCustomTableView=[[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(300, 180, 236, 672) style:UITableViewStylePlain];
    } else {
        self.myCustomTableView=[[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(113, 100, 196, 372) style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
    }
    [self.myCustomTableView setDelegate:self];
    [self.myCustomTableView setDataSource:self];
    [self.myCustomTableView setSeparatorStyle:UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleSingleLine];
    [self.myCustomTableView setSeparatorColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    self.myCustomTableView.opaque = NO;
    self.myCustomTableView.clipsToBounds = YES;
    self.myCustomTableView.layer.cornerRadius=8.0;
    [self.myCustomTableView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
    [self.view addSubview:self.myCustomTableView];
}


- (nonnull UITableViewCell *)tableView:(nonnull UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(nonnull NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Test"];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] init];
    }
    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Section: %li, Row: %li", indexPath.section, indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(nonnull UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 10;
}



@end
```

I suspect your tableview is never being added to the view hierarchy, you can use the "Debug View Hierarchy" while running your application to see what views are in the view hierarchy. The button for it is right at the top of the debug area which is near the bottom of the Xcode window.[image: Debug View Hierarchy Button]

The output of the above sample code looks like this:

[image: TableView Sample on iPhone Simulator]

Comment: Thank you, I have posted the `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

Comment: With that code - it also doesn't show a table :(

Comment: Does the tableview show up when you use the Debug View Hierarchy button as screen shotted in the answer?

Comment: No - with Debug View Hierarchy it doesn't show up either

Comment: Are you creating a new project and inserting that code into the default ViewController that's created or attempting to insert it into your existing project. If you're doing the latter, I would recommend attempting to do the former to confirm it's working for you there. If it does, then you may have to look further into your own project setup.

Comment: I just created a new project, and indeed it did show up fine, so something awry with my own project it would seem, very bizarre as I am not sure why it would just do that having been compatible up until maybe the last 3-4 years - I was expecting the layout to be off, but not disappearing ! :)

Answer (score 0):

OK, so it seems in my code, for some reason `ViewWillAppear` was not being called, so when switching to `ViewDidLoad` the tableview showed up.
Thank you to all that have helped.

Comment: Since you say you **were** adding the table view to the hierarchy, the most likely reason the rows were not being populated is because, if you're adding the table view in `viewWillAppear` you ***also*** need to call `.reloadData()`. But, the proper place to do all of that is in `viewDidLoad`

Comment: This makes perfect sense @DonMag